# Get the member who updated other member's roles discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there any way to get the member who edited my (or any other member in the guild) roles?

*Using discord.py, python version = 3.9.4

Comment: You can DM discord to add that feature, or remove perms, from everyone and to tell them to do these via ur bot so u know who did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Guild.audit_logs()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit#discord.Guild.audit_logs)

You could use

```py
async for entry in guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.role_update):
    print(f"{entry.user} changed role {entry.target}")
```

`.user` is the person who changed it

`.target` would be the role

You could fetch the latest one on a [`on_guild_role_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit#discord.on_guild_role_update) event